# How many times a word occurs in a file?

Tags: python

In my Python homework my assignment is to: "Write a complete python program that reads a file trash.txt and outputs how many times the word Bob occurs in the file."

My code is:

```
count=0
f=open('trash.txt','r')
bob_in_trash=f.readlines()
for line in bob_in_trash:
    if "Bob" in line:
        count=count+1
print(count)
f.close()
```

Is there any way to make this code more efficient? It counted 5 correctly but I was wondering if there's anything I could modify.

Comment: what if your file has two `bob`s on one line?

Comment: As Doorknob implies, you're counting the number of lines containing "Bob", not the number of times it occurs in the file.

Comment: Would words like "Bobby" and "kebob" be counted as well?

Answer (score 9):

You can just read the whole file and count the nomber of "Bob":

```
data = open('trash.txt').read()
count = data.count('Bob')
```

Although this is more accurate for smaller files, loading the whole file to memory might be a problem when you're dealing with bigger files.

Reading it line by line is still more efficient, but use `str.count` instead of `Bob in line` (which makes you read how many lines that has "Bob" in it).

```
with open('trash.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        count += line.count("Bob")
```

Comment: Depending on the word and the parameters of the search, it might be necessary to do something like `data = open("trash.txt").read().lower()` and search in lower case, but otherwise this is nice, quick and easy.

Answer (score 1):

This way you're always counting one "Bob" per line... How about using the `count` method, so you could sum any number of occurrences per line:

```
for line in bob_in_trash:
    count=count+line.count("Bob")
```

Answer (score 1):

For more versatility use regex to distinguish `bob`, `Bob`, `bobcat`, etc.

```
import re
with open('trash.txt','r') as f:
   count = sum(len(re.findall( r'\bbob\b', line)) for line in f)
```

### Options:

```
r'\bbob\b'      # matches bob
r'(?i)\bbob\b'  # matches bob, Bob
r'bob'          # matches bob, Bob, bobcat
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> count = 0
>>> abuffer = bytearray(4096)
>>> with open('trash.txt') as fp:
...    while fp.readinto(abuffer) > 0:
...        count += abuffer.count('Bob')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're looking for only whole words, it's best to use a regex:

```
i = 0
with open('trash.txt','r') as file:
    for result in re.finditer(r'\bBob\b', file.read()):
        i += 1
print('Number of Bobs in file: ' + str(i))
```

Note that the regular expression is `\bBob\b`, where the `\b` at the beggining and end mean that `Bob` must be a word, not part of a word. Also, I used `finditer` instead of `find` because the former uses much less memory for large files.

To save even more memory, combine with line-by-line reading:

```
i = 0
with open('trash.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for result in re.finditer(r'\bBob\b', line):
            i += 1
print('Number of Bobs in file: ' + str(i))
```