# I made a program that checks if a word in in a file, need some advice

Tags: python

I want to print if the word appears, as well as how many times the word appears in the file. I can't get it to say anything other than this word appears 1 or 0 times in the file.

`This problem occurs on line 26,  print("It appears " + str(wordcount[word]) + " times")`

specifically str(wordcount[word]). This probably simple question, but this is my first week of python so if anyone has an idea please share. Thanks!

I've tried putting `wordcount[word]`, `word_counter.__getitem__(wordcount[word])`, and `word_counter.__getitem__(wordcount)`

```
import collections
file = open(r"C:\Users\Patrick Wu\Documents\1wordfreqtest.txt", "r")
if file.mode == "r":
    contents = file.read()
word = input("Word to check for :")
wordcount = {}
"""this below is to remove difference between upper and lower cases as 
well as punctuation""" 
for word in contents.lower().split():
    word = word.replace(".","")
    word = word.replace(",","")
    word = word.replace(":","")
    word = word.replace("\"","")
    word = word.replace("!","")
    word = word.replace("â€œ","")
    word = word.replace("â€˜","")
    word = word.replace("*","")
    if word not in wordcount:
        wordcount[word] = 1
    else:
        wordcount[word] += 1

word_counter = collections.Counter(wordcount)
if word in str(contents):
    print("This word is in the file :)")
    print("It appears " + str(wordcount[word]) + " times")
else:
    print("This word isn't in the file")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many times a word occurs in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414989/how-many-times-a-word-occurs-in-a-file)

Comment: You're saving the user input in a variable called `word`.  But then you re-use that same variable name in the for loop, so you've lost its original value.  When the loop ends and you print the frequency message, `word` keeps whatever value it had on the last for loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `word` is overwritten in the local scope, by the loop.  So your input `word` is overwritten by the loop and you end up checking the count of the last word of the input file.  Change the input word to be a different variable name than the word you're iterating through in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```py
import collections
file = open("wordfreqtest.txt", "r")
if file.mode == "r":
    contents = file.read().lower()
word = input("Word to check for :").lower()

times = 0

finish = 0

while finish==0:
    if word in contents:
        contents = contents[contents.find(word) + len(word):]
        times += 1
    else:
        break

if times > 0:
    print("This word is in the file :)")
    print("It appears " + str(times) + " times")
else:
    print("This word isn't in the file")
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea people would answer so fast:)

Answer (score 1):

You have a scoping problem, by using the same name "word" both in the input and in the for-loop.

I would suggest doing something like this:

```
word = input("Word to check for :")
with open('your_file.txt') as f:
     raw = f.read()
     num_appearences = raw.count(word)
     print(f"The word {word} appears {num_appearences} times in the file")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but when I input the code, the {word} always becomes "fly" and not the actual input. Any idea on how that may have happened?

Comment: I don't but I solved the problem I had by creating another variable called if_word for the if statement. Thanks for your help though!